# Google search links obtain by webscraping in R are not in required format

Tags: r, rcurl

I am new to web scraping in R and trying to run google search action using a search term from R and extract links automatically. I am partially successful in obtaining the links of google search results using RCurl and XML package. However, the href links I extract include unwanted information and are not in the format of a "URL".

The code I use is:

```
html <- getURL(u)
links <- xpathApply(doc, "//h3//a[@href]", xmlGetAttr, 'href')
links <- grep("http://", links, fixed = TRUE, value=TRUE)
```

The above code gives me seven links, however, they are in the below format:

```
[1] "/url?q=http://theguitarrepairworkshop.com/services/&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiOnNXzsr7OAhWHAMAKHX_LApYQFggmMAM&usg=AFQjCNF1r13FMHXXTsxMkbwzortiWKDALQ"
```

I would prefer them to be:

```
http://theguitarrepairworkshop.com/services/
```

How do I extract the href as above?

Comment: scraping google is violation of their terms of service. i'll be glad to help if you mock up a different scraping example.

Comment: *Does RCurl/XML Package use Xpath 1.0 or Xpath 2.0?* If it uses 2.0, a regex function in the xpath statement will give simpler code and faster performance.

Comment: @hrbrmstr: Thank you for letting me know. I was not aware of that. Are there any other legal alternatives to fetch search results from the internet via an application.

Comment: DuckDuckGo provides you an API but not complete search results https://duckduckgo.com/api

Comment: @amrrs: Thanks, again. That`s helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `rvest` package (which also uses `XML` package but has a lot of handy features related to scraping)

```
library(rvest)
ht <- read_html('https://www.google.co.in/search?q=guitar+repair+workshop')
links <- ht %>% html_nodes(xpath='//h3/a') %>% html_attr('href')
gsub('/url\\?q=','',sapply(strsplit(links[as.vector(grep('url',links))],split='&'),'[',1))
```

Output:

```
[1] "http://theguitarrepairworkshop.com/"                                                                   
[2] "http://www.justdial.com/Delhi-NCR/Guitar-Repair-Services/ct-134788"                                    
[3] "http://www.guitarrepairshop.com/"                                                                      
[4] "http://www.guitarworkshoponline.com/"                                                                  
[5] "http://www.guitarrepairbench.com/guitar-building-projects/guitar-workshop/guitar-workshop-project.html"
[6] "http://www.guitarservices.com/"                                                                        
[7] "http://guitarworkshopglasgow.com/pages/repairs-1"                                                      
[8] "http://brightonguitarworkshop.co.uk/"                                                                  
[9] "http://www.luth.org/resources/schools.html"
```

The fourth line in the code cleans the text. First splits the resulted url (that comes with garbage) wrt '&' and then takes the first element of the resulted split and replaces '/url?q=' with empty.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It solves the issue. I was considering strsplit option, however, was wondering if I was doing something wrong in fetching the href nodes.

Comment: `html_nodes(xpath='//h3/a')`  This solution no longer works.