# Google Searching in R

Tags: r

This question is not so much about how to google search in R (discussed many times before) as much as why it does not always work.

I found this code from another posted question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38932982/google-search-links-obtain-by-webscraping-in-r-are-not-in-required-format)
That I recall working perfectly. It would produce all the links in the search.

But now it does not work. For some reason the   node is not there anymore when I pull the data into R. But when I actually inspect the html code on Chrome it's there when I am browsing the code. It show's the `h3` node in the display inspector but not when it's being downloded.

```
library(rvest)
ht <- read_html('https://www.google.co.in/search?q=guitar+repair+workshop')
links <- ht %>% html_nodes(xpath='//h3/a') %>% html_attr('href')
gsub('/url\\?q=','',sapply(strsplit(links[as.vector(grep('url',links))],split='&'),'[',1))
```

I get the following return:

```
 character(0)
```

The google page display of links depends on your location/preferences. So maybe this is what is causing the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the format switched very recently, maybe today, and that the //h3 is no longer used. This produces what is intended with one final extraneous result

```
    library(rvest)
    ht <- read_html('https://www.google.co.in/search?q=guitar+repair+workshop')
    links <- ht %>% html_nodes(xpath='//a') %>% html_attr('href')
    gsub('/url\\?q=','',sapply(strsplit(links[as.vector(grep('url',links))],split='&'),'[',1))
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. But may I ask. What do you mean the format switched? Was this a change by Google? Are they doing this to prevent people from web scraping?

Comment: I don't know why changed it but it appears something related to how Google formats the tags for their search results changed. They used to include a 'h3' in the tag for every search result and now they do not. Just from searching for other solutions that used to perform this say functionality it seems that before '//h3/a' google used to use "//a[@href][@class='l']" (see the comment in this one - https://www.r-bloggers.com/web-scraping-google-urls/). I don't think it is particularly anti-web scraping but old solutions will fail everytime they do change the format in which they tag the results.